# Extract labels from classifier using python

Tags: python, entity, stanford-nlp, label

I am using Standford NER for getting the words and entities using different classifier in python.I use StanfordNERTagger and user defined classifier to get these entities for the respective words.

My Code Looks like:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

input_text = ['Admission : 12 June 2016, Service: done, Allergies: NL']
s = StanfordNERTagger("ClassifierName",'stanford-ner.jar',encoding='utf-8')
tokenized_text = word_tokenize(input_text)
classified_text = s.tag(tokenized_text)
```

The above code gives me the words present in the input "input_text" and their entities. But I need to get all the entity types present in the classifer depending upon the classifier I select. How can I get all those entity types in python?